# can't access cookies on a rest response in angular

Tags: angularjs, cookies, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

I have an angular front end with a webapi back end. I have implemented OAuth v2 security using OWIN/Identity and JWT tokens (thanks to Taiseer Joudeh's blogs).  My burden is that we still have legacy pages that require a specific cookie.  I have augmented the Http Response from WebApi to include that cookie when the JWT token is returned from a login request.  I have verified the cookie is in the response header.

My problem is that I am unable to see the cookie inside my angular response handler where I will push it to the browser.  I have tried each of the following based on suggestions I found elsewhere within StackOverflow but so far visibility of the cookie within the .js code has eluded me (alternate attempts have been commented out but left in for completeness).  I have also made sure I set the appropriate "allow" fields on the server by adding "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" to "set-cookie" and "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" to "true" at the end of my ValidateClientAuthenticationContext(..) method.

What do I need to do to see the attached cookie on my webapi response?  Is this a problem on the server or client? both?

in my authService.js file:

```
var _login = function (loginData) {

    // this makes the data "form data"
    var data = "grant_type=password&client_id=ngAuthApp&username=" + loginData.userName + "&password=" + loginData.password;

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.post(serviceBase + 'oauth/token', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } })
        .success(function (response) {

            localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token, userName: loginData.userName });

            _authentication.isAuth = true;
            _authentication.userName = loginData.userName;

                console.log($cookies);

            //var xxx = $http.defaults.headers;
            //var headers = $http.response.headers;

            var ddc = $http.response.cookies;
            $cookies.DDC = ddc;

            deferred.resolve(response);

        })
        //.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        //    // any required additional processing here 
        //    var results = [];
        //    results.data = data;
        //    results.headers = headers();
        //    results.status = status;
        //    results.config = config;

        //    deferred.resolve(results);
        //})
        .error(function (err, status) {
            _logOut();
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

    return deferred.promise;

};
```

in my custom OAuthProvider .cs file

public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            // skipping over lots of code here

```
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", new[] { "true" });
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", new[] { "authorization", "content-type", "set-cookie" });

        context.Validated();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out the error was in my assumptions.  I expected that a cookie sent via a web service directly from embedded js code would be ignored by the browser.  However, the response header has the "Set-Cookie" value in the header and the browser IS already pushing it to be with the rest of the cookies.  I really didn't expect that.

I must add this has been a very useful question for me because it taught me a lot about web programming and how the browser works with http header values.  I appreciate everyone's time!

Marcus

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs - see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

`$http.post()` method returns an `HttpPromise` future object.  Your call to .post() returns a promise. Which according to the Deprecation Notice on the above referenced page :

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
>   $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
>   methods will throw $http/legacy error.

So instead of .success() / error(), use this: (Copied from docs)

```
$http.post()
.then(function successCallback(response) {
  // this callback will be called asynchronously
  // when the response is available
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  // called asynchronously if an error occurs
  // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Also, if you haven't already tried this (according to the .post() call it doesn't appear to) set the `responseType` property of your `$http` configuration `object`. This sets the `datatype` of the `response` object returned. Otherwise the `default` of a `DOM string` is returned. It may not fix it but it could be a start.

This could also need the help of `withCredentials` property set. Test them out and see how it goes. Idea comes from the suggestion of `bastijn`.

Comment: Great response!  I learned a lot from it!  Specifically, by switching to the "promise" version I was able to get an 'response' that included both the request header and the data.  With the ".success" version the value in the 'response' was simply the data.  That being said, I am still not able to the cookie from within the angular code.

Answer (score 0):

Your $http call should also set the withCredentials flag to true to explicitly allow cookie sharing.

```
$http.post(url, {withCredentials: true, ...})
```

The withCredentials flag allows javascript to access the authenticated session of the user.

//edit 
Now that I read your question again this is probably not your issue. The withCredentials is to,communicate your session to the server on the next request you make that requires the authenticated session. From your question it seems you want to validate in the js code that the cookie you verified is there is also reachable by code.

Comment: yes, i simply want to access the cookie in the response from the login.  still, i went ahead and added your suggestion to make sure it wasn't a fix and, unfortunately, i verified the problem remains.  thank you for trying.

Comment: Yes. You will need this only for your future requests you need to make where the authorized session is required.